# Semantic UI React, Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Please take a look at my code for Dropdown, 
I'm using the semantic ui react dropdown on an EditProfile component. I have pasted a sample code here, https://codesandbox.io/s/m4288nx4z8, but I could not get it to work because I'm not very familiar with functional components in React, I've always used Class component. But you can check the full code for the whole component below in the github gist.
https://gist.github.com/mayordwells/b0cbb7b63af85269091f1f98296fd9bb

Please, I need help on inserting values from multiple select options of a Dropdown into the Database and also a way to display that back upon viewing the profile edit page again.

I'm using semantic-ui-react in react + rails app.

Also when I insert a value using a normal drop down without multiple select, the value gets persisted into the database.

```
<Dropdown
  placeholder='Select Country'
  fluid
  search
  selection
  options={countryOptions}
  name='country'
  defaultValue={this.state.extraInfo.country}
  onChange={(e) => this.handleExtraInfoChange('country', e)}
/>
```

This code handles change for the dropdown elements.

```
handleExtraInfoChange = (name, event) => {
      let value;

      if (event.target.value !== undefined) {
        value = event.target.value;
      } else {
        value = event.target.textContent;
      }

      let newExtraInfo = Object.assign(this.state.extraInfo, { [name]: value })

      this.setState({ extraInfo: newExtraInfo});
    }
```

But when I visit the page again, I get a white blank in the input box. Here's a screen pic for that. When I comment out the defaultValue or value property(i have tried with defaultValue and value), the white blank disappears, but the value picked by a user is also not seen.
[image]

Please advice what is a possible solution to this misbehavior? And what is the best way to insert multiple values into the Database?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A functional component does not have state, it's used for composition; you want to store state, so you either have to create a `Component` class or you need an external state container like `redux`.

Comment: check the real code in the GitHub gist I shared. I am using a class component.

Comment: Where do you load the data? There's only an async save? Also: multiple values can be stored in various ways, really up to you. You can merge them in a string using some separation, or store them in a separate table.

Comment: The data is loaded from a separate file, like countries.js, where I exported countryOptions from, saved into a rails database upon selected by a user. Currently, data is being saved using the existing, `handleExtraInfo` function. The only data that isn't saved are the ones from the multiple select, like the languages? What's the easiest way to save that? Honestly, I don't know how to do this. I think we should address this issue before the other issue with the white blank.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The multiple value is stored in an array. How it is serialized to the server depends on the implementation used. If you serialize the values using JSON, you can save the serialized JSON string in the database, but that won't search well. So you can deserialize the JSON object on the server and save the values as a character delimited value (requires deserialization on the server when the user requests the resource) or use an relational table, in which case you need to deserialize, create insert/update -> and select -> serialize when responding to a request.

Comment: That said, there are frameworks that can do the marshalling of JSON data for you, for example `Grails` (a spring-boot groovy framework)